# Overloading property

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I have a class A which contains an object of class B as property. I want to derive class B and also want to make sure that the property in class A points to the derived class object. So for that I guess I need to derive class A also overloading that property. So here is the structure:

```
public class A {
  public List<B> X{get; set;}
}

public class B {
}

public class C : B {
  string extraProperty {get; set;}
}

public class D : A {
     // I want property X to be of type C.
}
```

I tried declaring property X in class A as virtual and then using overriding X in class D but that gives an error that `D:X must be of type B to match overriden member A:X`. I read that C# does not support property overloading. Any suggestions how can I do this?

Edit:
I cannot change classes A and B since they are being used somewhere else.

Comment: make class `A` generic

Comment: what is preventing you from making a `List<C>` in class A ?

Comment: Can you give us a proper usage scenario? You can certainly make properties `virtual`.

Comment: @Sniffer: I get this error message that property X defined in D must be of type B to match overriden member.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I declared the property in class A virtual and then use overriden in class D but it gives me the error I described above.

Comment: You can't "override" a `List<B>` to be a `List<C>` - `virtual` won't help you here. Note that since `C` inherits `B`, you can still put `C` into `X` - but you'll have to cast anything that comes out.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated in the comments the way to do this is through Generics.

```
public class A<T> where T : B {
    public List<T> X { get; set; }
}

public class B {
}

public class C : B {
    string ExtraProperty { get; set; }
}

public class D : A<C> {
   // Property X is of type C.
}

public class E : A<B> {
   // Property X is of type B.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is *extremely* rare that one should ever expose a `List<T>` as a read-write property.  An `IList<T>` occasionally, but the only time a `List<T>` should ever be exposed by a property is when the property is supposed to identify a list, rather than encapsulate its contents.

I suspect that what you really want to be doing is hold a private list or array, and have a property which returns a wrapper object that will allow access to it via `IList<T>` interface.  If only read-only access is to be permitted, and a base class holds a list of `BaseFoo` and has a property of type `IList<BaseFoo>`, a derived class could hold a collection of `DerivedFoo` and have its property return an `IList<DefivedFoo>`.  Code which casts a derive-class reference to base-class type and then requests the property would get an `IList<BaseFoo>`.

Note that if you want to have read-write access to the collection, that approach won't really work.  If code casts a derived-class object to a base-class object, it could then get an `IList<BaseFoo>`.  If it was allowed to write to that, the collection would no longer consist only of `DerivedFoo`.